# Is there a way to inform Application Insights about route structure?

Tags: azure-application-insights

My .Net Framework Web API has a few endpoints, all structured in a similar way.

```
Endpoint1 - /User/{userId}/Resource1/{resourceId}/...
Endpoint2 - /User/{userId}/Resource2/{resourceId}/...
```

This pattern can be more sub-resources deep.

However, this turns out to be a bit problematic in the various tools in Application Insights. The errors blade show each operation by their individual URL. Not grouped by endpoint.
I can easily see if /User/123/Resource1/abc/ is causing errors but it is difficult to tell if that particular endpoint is problematic. Makes sense?

Is there a way to inform Application Insights to be more smart in how it groups operations in the UI and the other tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [telemetry initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#add-properties-itelemetryinitializer) to modify OperationName. In your case you can replace actual identifiers with "{userId}" and "{resourceId}"